# Limit point definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition

I have read the definition of a limit point of a set in Real Analysis.

The definition goes like:
A number $p$ is said to be a limit point of a set of reals, $S$, if every neigbourhood of $p$ has at least one element of the set $S$ different from $p$.
I worked out that any open interval of the form $(p-d,p+d)$, $d$ is greater than 0, is a neighbourhood of $p$. And, any neighbourhood has at least one element of $S$ (say $s$).

My question is, why is the term limit there? Can I find a similarity with the limit of function?

Comment: Well, there is an analogy to the limit of a *sequence*. $p$ is a limit point of $S$ if and only if there is a sequence in $S \setminus p$ whose limit is $p$.

Comment: If the brackets are acting funny it's probably better to change the interval notation to $(p-d,p+d)$, which is the more usual notation for open intervals, than to put the brackets outside the dollar signs.

Comment: If the interval notation is funny, please make it serious.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is some similarity with the notion of the limit of a function, but I think there is more similarity with the notion of the limit of a *sequence*. Namely, a point $x$ is a limit point of a set of reals $S$ if and only if there is a sequence $(x_n :n \in \mathbb{N})$ of reals whose limit is $x$ and such that each $x_n$ belongs to the set $S$ and is not equal to the given point $x$.